# mysql server cant start

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

im try to install phpmyadmin but suddenly i cant start my mysql server how to make it run again for error

> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>    Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
>   start: Job failed to start
>   invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
>   dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    mysql-server-5.6
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I had read that one can use apt-get remove purge but ,if i do like that all my mysql data will gone and i dont want that happen how should to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try in terminal 
@sudo dpkg --configure -a